# How to publish a navigation goal to turtlebot running the amcl_demo.launch navigation with a map file

Tags: navigation, rviz, turtlebot, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish navigation goals to the turtlebot running the amcl_demo.launch with a specific map file.

In general when amcl_demo.launch file is launched with the mapfile, we can send the navigation goals to the turtlebot using the Rviz GUI tool. But i want to send the navigation goals to the turtlebot form a pyhton script that i have written the Navigation Goal parameters in it.

I could figure out that, the Rviz sends the navigation goals to the topic /move_base_simple/goal. I want to know the correct message format of the navigation goal that should be sent to the turtlebot.

How do i get this task done??
Anyone who knows the answer, please help me.

Thank You

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104321/how-to-publish-a-navigation-goal-to-turtlebot-running-the-amcl_demo.launch-navigation-with-a-map-file/) by [bhanodhaynss](https://answers.ros.org/users/9106/bhanodhaynss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this what you are looking for.

```
rostopic pub /move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped '{ header: {stamp: now, frame_id: "map"}, pose: { position: {x: -4.560, y: 0.204, z: 0.0}, orientation: {w: 1.0}}}'
```

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhanodhaynss](https://answers.ros.org/users/9106/bhanodhaynss/) on 2013-11-24**:
Yes rnunziata, this is what i was searching for...Thank You
can you please let me know the source of this answer, so that i would go into the details of it

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2013-11-25**:
The information is here: http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html.

**Comment by [bhanodhaynss](https://answers.ros.org/users/9106/bhanodhaynss/) on 2013-11-25**:
Thank You rnunziata

**Comment by [potatoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/67135/potatoo/) on 2021-02-02**:
hi your information link is no more able to see. Can it possible to post again? As I'm actually not very understand the published meaning of the code.